# Почему не получаю json данные?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, recyclerview.adapter, android-threads

Нужно получить JSON данные, однако я получаю ошибку и не могу понять, в чём проблема
Есть ссылка https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-25-01&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=5ada8e399698405dad35cd8f37877a4f

Вот мой код на Java в Android Studio, который я вызываю из **фрагмента**:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-25-01&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=5ada8e399698405dad35cd8f37877a4f");
                    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.connect();

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }

                    output = stringBuilder.toString(); //Выходная JSON строка

                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          // Здесь я заполняю адаптер
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (httpURLConnection != null)
                        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                    if (bufferedReader != null) {
                        try {
                            bufferedReader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }, "news_request").start();
```

Однако я не могу заполнить мой Adapter т.к.

```
W/FA-Ads: Analytics storage consent denied; will not get app instance id
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-25-01&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=5ada8e399698405dad35cd8f37877a4f
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.plumsoftware.news.MenuFragment$1.run(MenuFragment.java:132)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Строка с ошибкой:

```
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

Кроме того в файле Манифеста прописаны соответствующие разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Кто разбирается, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы пробовали отдебажить, что приходит в ответе от сервера?

Comment: @JVic нет не пробовал отдеважить.

Comment: Попробуйте  варианты отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365829/filenotfoundexception-for-httpurlconnection-in-ice-cream-sandwich

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ссылка возвращает код ошибки `426` (перейдите по своей ссылке в браузере, нажмите `F12` откройте там вкладку `сеть` и обновите страницу), а получить данные в случае ошибок `4хх` и `5хх` через `httpURLConnection.getInputStream()` не получится.

Вам нужно получить код ответа на запрос:

```
int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Проверяйте код статуса ответа, и если возвращается `4хх` или `5хх`, то получить ответ можно так:

```
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
```

Попробуйте такой код (сам его не проверял, накидал на коленках):

```
InputStream inputStream;
if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
   inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
}
else {
   inputStream=httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
}
```